# Test method called in mounted hook Vue class component typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am trying to test that a method is called on mount of Vue component. Fairly new to Vue and Typescript.

```
export default class App extends Vue {
    mounted () {
        this.deviceId()
        this.ipAddress()
        this.channel()
        this.show()
        this.campaign()
        this.adUnit()
    }
```

this approach works but I get a warning:

```
    it('mounted methods are called', async () => {
        
        const deviceId = jest.fn()
        wrapper = shallowMount(App, {
            methods: {
                deviceId
            }
        })
        expect(deviceId).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

The error:

```
 console.error node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:1735
      [vue-test-utils]: overwriting methods via the `methods` property is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. There is no clear migration path for the `methods` property - Vue does not support arbitrarily replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex method extract it from the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests.
```

I have tried using jest spyOn, but I cannot find a way to access the method;

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'methodName')
wrapper = shallowMount(App)
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Gives the following error:

```
 Cannot spy the deviceId property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

The following also doesn't work:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.methods, 'methodName')
```

Error:

```
Property 'methods' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.ts(2339)
```

And the following:

```
        const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype.methods, 'deviceId')
```

Error:

```
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given
```

I have read in places I may need to define an interface for the component but I am not sure how this works with defining functions inside or if it is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same issue for a few days, but I've found the way of pointing to the correct method when calling `jest.spyOn()`.

It's a bit tricky but you'll find the methods of your class like this:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype.constructor.options.methods, 'deviceId');
```

Note that (even if it might seem obvious, just in case) you'll need to do this **before** wrapping your component, i.e. like this:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype.constructor.options.methods, 'deviceId');
wrapper = mount(App, { /* Your options go here */ });
```

By the way, you don't need to define methods property inside options.

Comment: on `npm run serve`: 

`Property 'options' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

Comment: You're right, I'm getting same error. However.. it's weird. I don't know why, first of all, tests has something to do with `serve/build` the project. Also, I get there just because I was _console.logging_ the object and its properties/methods and actually works (the tests pass and I've verified the method is being called) because the method is actually there.. So I definitely don't know why this should be an error.. at most it should be a warning..

Anyway... I'm afraid then there is no way to test methods right now using jest and Typescript.. seems like a bug, I'll open an issue

Comment: I guess that, until it's solved or we get a better approach.. I'll need to comment it to build/serve the project and uncomment when testing the app...

Comment: Thank you so much for opening an issue, I will continue to dig into it as well.

Comment: Just in case you want to have a look or add something else https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1623

Comment: Anything new with this? I am also stuck and the guy in the issue says to not test like this at all, also any example he gives is with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Define your method under the property `methods`. Only then you can access them from the class.

```
export default class App extends Vue {
    methods: {
        deviceId(){
            console.log("do your stuff")
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html) for more examples for the usage of `methods`